# Springboot Load-Time Weaving doesn't allow to inject a spring bean into an aspect for embedded Tomcat when devtools is used

Tags: spring-boot, aspectj, load-time-weaving, embedded-tomcat-8, spring-boot-devtools

I'm using pretty recent springboot v1.5.2 with aspectj's (v1.8.10) load time weaving. I was able to inject a spring bean into my aspectj aspect while running my application on an external tomcat and now I wonder why just the same failed for the embedded tomcat?

springboot: **1.5.2**

Aspectj: **1.8.10**

Spring instrumentation: **4.3.7.RELEASE**

maven command: **mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments=" -javaagent:aspectjweaver-1.8.10.jar -javaagent:spring-instrument-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar -Dserver.port=8080 -Dserver.contextPath=/custom-application"**

aspect config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class AspectConfig {

    @Bean
    public RuntimeContainerDelegateAspect runtimeContainerDelegateAspect() {
        return Aspects.aspectOf(RuntimeContainerDelegateAspect.class);
    }}
```

aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class RuntimeContainerDelegateAspect {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RuntimeContainerDelegateAspect.class);

    @Autowired
    private RestApplicationDeployer deployer;


    @Pointcut("execution(* org.someapp.container.impl.RuntimeContainerDelegateImpl.deployApplication(..))")
    public void deployApplication() {
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* org.someapp.container.impl.RuntimeContainerDelegateImpl.undeployProcessApplication(..))")
    public void undeployApplication() {
    }

    @Around("deployApplication()")
    public void aroundDeploy(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        if (LOGGER.isInfoEnabled())
            LOGGER.info("RuntimeDelegateCalled: " + pjp.toString());
        AbstractProcessApplication app = (AbstractProcessApplication) pjp.getArgs()[0];
        LOGGER.debug("deployer={}", deployer);
        deployer.deploy(app);
    }

    @Around("undeployApplication()")
    public void aroundUndeploy(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        if (LOGGER.isInfoEnabled())
            LOGGER.info("RuntimeDelegateCalled: " + pjp.toString() + "\n" +
                        "Default implementation does nothing.");
    }

}
```

deployer:

```
@Component
public class RestApplicationDeployer {
//it's just an ordinary spring bean
}
```

Actual result: **deployer = null, since aspectj creates new instance of the RuntimeContainerDelegateAspect for processing @Around advice**

Expected result: deployer = **spring bean RestApplicationDeployer**

P.S: **This works perfectly on an external tomcat instance**

Comment: You haven't provided any information about how you configured the external Tomcat instance where you say it worked. I suspect the difference in behaviour lies in a difference in the configuration.

Comment: Well, don't have much interesting to say here. 
I took vanilla tomcat > 8.0.28, extended its CATALINA_OPTS in startup.sh by adding -javaagent:$CATALINA_BASE/aspectjweaver-1.8.10.jar \
-javaagent:$CATALINA_BASE/spring-instrument-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar 
I tried it both in Intellij IDEA and on CentOS 6. 
JDK 1.8u > 102 was used for experiments

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I created an example project for you
https://github.com/karuniko/springboot-aspectj-example
Could you please take a look? The issue is reproduced there

Comment: One note: it's only reproducible when devtools jar is defined as a dependency